# Как при вводе с клавиатуры набора чисел в одну строку преобразовать её в массив int

Tags: golang

Входные данные(прям в таком формате): 2 2 2 2 2
Предложите пожалуйста варианты как этот набор чисел преобразовать в массив типа int

Comment: На голанге - ручками... можно получить массив строк и конвертнуть каждый элемент, но лучше создать ридера и вычитывать сразу в нужный тип.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = "2 2 2 2 2";    
let intArr = str.split(" ").map(a => parseInt(a));
console.log(intArr);
```

Comment: а есть вариант не использовать строки?

Comment: а какой по вашему тип данных сможет содержать вот такие данные **"2 2 2 2 2"**, кроме строк ?

Comment: А какой у вас тип данных у 2 2 2 2 2 может быть, кроме как не строка?

Comment: а, правда, логично, не подумал (

Comment: @DanilApsadikov кстати, а вы просто промазали с ЯП или теги не смотрели? это не по JS вопрос :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Теги не смотрел

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "2 2 2 2 2"
var intArr []int

strArr := strings.Split(str, " ")
    
for _, v := range strArr {
    i, _ := strconv.Atoi(v)
    intArr = append(intArr, i) 
}

fmt.Println(intArr)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]